# run a program inside bash script without doing it orphaned process

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'd like to know if there's a way to run a program inside a bash script without doing it orphaned process. In other words, I want to launch a process with a bash script but I don't want this process becomes orphaned process.

Comment: Why do you think a process you run in a script will become an orphan?

Comment: run a bash script that launch a program and then you give this command to see orphaned process: ps -elf | awk '{if ($5 == 1){print $4" "$5" "$15}}' In this way you may see your process with orphaned process. It has INIT's ppid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the parent alive. So in the script ask it to wait:

```
start_the_process &
wait $! #or without the parameter to wait for all
```

And now call the script with either:

```
script
```

or

```
script &
```

to have it in the background.

Comment: I didn't fix it in this way. In my bash I have

./program 35 3 10000 > /tmp/program.log 2>&1 &

script command write into my bash file.

Comment: Fixed, with your method. I've put wait after running process into bash. In order to run the script I've used ./nomescript &. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MassimilianoD Good. You can then accept the answer with the check on the left by the answer.

Comment: This method works with normal script, but what if is it a sbin/runscript inside /etc/init.d ?

Comment: @MassimilianoD Better ask this as a new question.